# Create a windows 10 bootable installation media with latest updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, bootable-media

How can I create a windows 10 bootable installation media with latest updates along with it ? So that when I have to use it at places with slow internet connections, I don't have to sit there for ever.

Thanks.

Comment: In short, you need to download the offline packages and copy them to the ISO using DISM. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/servicing-the-image-with-windows-updates-sxs

Comment: Windows 10 changes frequently. The best approach is the Media Creation Link ISO at each point when a feature upgrade is issued.

Comment: I have always used Nlite for this>>>>https://www.nliteos.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is called [slipstreaming](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/slipstream-windows-10-integrate-updates-setup-media-iso/), i.e., creating a build of an ISO image and then integrating the latest updates It is a rather complex task, and may fail for *many* reasons (as I've found... *sigh*). It also requires the updates be for *specific* configurations, because some updates are not applicable for specific hardware, or updates must have drivers specific to that chipset.

PC-Steps also has a (naturally) [step-by-step guide to slipstreaming updates](https://www.pcsteps.com/13667-slipstream-drivers-updates-custom-windows-iso/) in to Windows ISO.

Trying to build the slipstreamed ISO is useful as an educational experience, but it rarely saves time, unless the ISO is to be installed on a fleet of identical machines, as in a corporate or educational environment.

As mentioned by @John, build the ISO after a major update and avoid the arduous slipstreaming process.